# Поддержка Unicode - C++ Windows Forms

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2015, c++-cli

Хотел написать простенький блокнот. Я считываю текст из файл при помощи openFileDialog и отправляю его в richTextBox. Как заставить его корректно читать кириллицу? На выходе получаю ток: �

Comment: Эээ... А как это вы ухитряетесь читать файл при помощи OpenFileDialog? Покажите ваш код. Вангую неуказанную кодировку.

Comment: То есть открываю файл через него и и читаю при помощи StramReader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил вот, в начале нужно прописать

```
System::Text::Encoding^ code = System::Text::Encoding::GetEncoding(1251);
```

И указать кодировку через *code* непосредственно при считывании. В целом будет выглядеть так:

```
private: System::Void openToolStripMenuItem1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

System::Text::Encoding^ code = System::Text::Encoding::GetEncoding(1251);
if (openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
{
    System::IO::StreamReader ^ sr = gcnew
        System::IO::StreamReader(openFileDialog1->FileName, code);
     richTextBox1->Text = sr->ReadToEnd();
    sr->Close();
}
```

}